# passing data to Angular ngbModalRef

Tags: angular, url-routing, jhipster

I'm trying to learn Angular using JHipster. I want to use the generated entity code popup (delete entity - in my case FTPshelf) to work in a different way. I want the popup to print a dynamic form checkbox + auditType entity.name.

Whatever I do It only works for first opening of popup. After I close it and open again the entity list doesn't populate.

My code:

html front:

```
<form name="chooseAuditForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="audit()" #chooseAuditForm="ngForm"
          (change)="chooseAudit(chooseAuditForm)">
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-inline" *ngFor="let auditType of auditTypes">
                <div class="col-lg-6">{{auditType.name}}</div>
                <div class="col-lg-6"><input id={{auditType.id}} type="checkbox" ngModel name="chosenAudit"
                            class="form-control" value={{auditType}}/></div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

ts component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-ftp-shelf-audit-dialog',
    templateUrl: './ftp-shelf-audit-dialog.component.html'
})
export class FtpShelfAuditDialogComponent {
    ftpShelf: IFtpShelf;

    constructor(private ftpShelfService: FtpShelfService,
                public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
                private eventManager: JhiEventManager) {
    }

    clear() {
        this.activeModal.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    confirmAudit(id: number) {
        this.ftpShelfService.delete(id).subscribe(response => {
            this.eventManager.broadcast({
                name: 'ftpShelfListModification',
                content: 'Audit an ftpShelf'
            });
            this.activeModal.dismiss(true);
        });
    }

    chooseAudit(chooseAuditForm: HTMLFormElement) {

    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-ftp-shelf-audit-popup',
    template: ''
})
export class FtpShelfAuditPopupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private ngbModalRef: NgbModalRef;
    private auditTypes: IAuditType[];

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router,
                private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
                private auditTypeService: AuditTypeService,
                private modalService: NgbModal) {
    }

    private onError(errorMessage: string) {
        this.jhiAlertService.error(errorMessage, null, null);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getAuditTypes();
        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ftpShelf}) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.ngbModalRef = this.modalService.open(FtpShelfAuditDialogComponent as Component, {
                    size: 'lg',
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });
                this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.ftpShelf = ftpShelf;
                this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.auditTypes = this.auditTypes;
                this.ngbModalRef.result.then(
                    result => {
                        this.router.navigate([{outlets: {popup: null}}], {
                            replaceUrl: true,
                            queryParamsHandling: 'merge'

                        });
                        this.ngbModalRef = null;
                    },
                    reason => {
                        this.router.navigate([{outlets: {popup: null}}], {
                            replaceUrl: true,
                            queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
                        });
                        this.ngbModalRef = null;
                    }
                );
            }, 0);

        });
    }

    getAuditTypes() {
        this.auditTypeService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IAuditType[]>) => {
                this.auditTypes = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngbModalRef = null;
    }

}
```

What I'm doing wrong? I understand that I should somehow else populate the variable auditTypes but nothing comes to mind. Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: The `auditTypes` are passed into the component via `this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.auditTypes = this.auditTypes;`

Comment: I assume that this is the problem, but FTPshelf is passed in the same way and it instantiates everytime. Any idea how should I do it correctly so that the data is there everytime I open the modal ? My next step is after checking checkboxex and pushing  confirm button to send a list of auditTypes to the controller to do some operations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I moved the

```
this.ngbModalRef.componentInstance.auditTypes = this.auditTypes;
```

just under the this.getAuditTypes